How to serve static files from different locations in NGINX
I want to serve static files from different two Django apps. one static files for the admin app and other static files for the pages app.
Note: I am aware of collectstatic command. What I would like to know is that, if there is a way to serve static files from two different directories under /static/ location. If one location failed, check the other location.
Locations for static files:

/webapps/project/admin/static and /webapps/project/pages/static

location /static/ {
    alias /webapps/project/admin/static/;
    alias /webapps/project/pages/static/;
}

This raise an error of duplicate alias directive
Here is what I wish to have. To check the files in @static, if file not found check in the @static2 block.
server {
    server_name x.x.x.x;

    client_max_body_size 8M;

    access_log /webapps/logs/project/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/logs/project/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        try_files $uri @static @static2;
    }

    location @static {
        root /webapps/project/pages/;
    }

    location @static2 {
        root /webapps/project/admin/;
    }

}

How should I serve both static files from two directories.

You can use try_files to check two paths, but you need to set root to a common parent directory.
For example:
location /static/ {
    root /webapps/project;
    try_files /pages$uri /admin$uri =404;
}

